# SUSY Kinetic and $W$ potential terms: RG flow --- free or interacting

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, supersymmetry

In [this Seiberg's SUSY lecture](https://youtu.be/sQGAWwUX_js?t=328), the professor said that the following theory with Kinetic and $W$ potential terms:

$$
K=|\phi|^2
$$
$$
W=m\phi^2+g \phi^3
$$

1. "It is not a valid theory in $4d$, but it is infrared (IR) free, thus it is not an interacting QFT."
2. "In $2d$ and $3d$, they are valid interacting QFTs."

Could someone explain the logic?

- what do free (quadratic lagrangian?) and interacting (higher order non-quadratic lagrangian?) mean respect to UV or respect to IR?
- I thought the $K=|\phi|^2$ requires derivative to be a kinetic term? Is he incorrect?
- I thought the $W=m\phi^2+g \phi^3$ are both relevant operators in the IR in 4d. Thus $g \phi^3$ changes the IR dynamics? Should this lead to an interacting QFT in 4d at IR?
- I thought the $m\phi^2$ is relevant and $g \phi^3$ is a marginal operator in the IR in 3d. Thus $g \phi^3$ again changes the IR dynamics? Should this lead to an interacting QFT in 3d?
- I thought the $m\phi^2$ is marginal and $g \phi^3$ is an irrelevant operator in the IR in 2d. Should this lead to a free QFT in 2d?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The terms $K$ and $W$ are not kinetic and potential terms, rather $K$ is a *K"ahler potential* and $W$ is a *superpotential*. Neither term enters the Lagrangian directly, but they are used to construct it. For details see, for example, [Cyril Closset's lecture notes on supersymmetry](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/44940).

Comment: thanks but how about the other parts of puzzles on interacting theory or not?

Comment: To check the properties of the theory (i.e. if and how it interacts) you would first need to compute the Lagrangian generated by these potentials.

Comment: thanks I voted up +1 -- does that lecture note contain all these aspects?

Comment: It does :) As an aside, the standard reference for SUSY (which Seiberg mentions in that lecture) is usually Wess and Bagger.